# Differentitation and Integeration

Tags: calculus, slope

I am trying to solve a differentiation/integration. I know the following relationship that indicates the rate of change of $x$ with time.

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = H\dfrac{dy}{dt} - kx$, where $H$ and $k$ are constants.

The value for $y\in(y_1, y_2,...)$ can be known at each time step. I am now trying to find the value of $x$ at each time step but I am not able to. Your kind feedback would be really helpful. :)

Regards,
venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

By letting $\;\varphi(t)=H\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\,,\,$ the differential equation turns into:

$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}+kx=\varphi(t)\;.$

The general solution of the homogeneous differential equation
$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}+kx=0\quad$ is $\quad\;\;x(t)=Ae^{-kt}\;,\;\;$ where $\;A\in\Bbb R\;.$

Let $\displaystyle\;B(t)=\int_0^t\!\varphi(u)e^{ku}\mathrm du\;.$

The general solution of the differential equation

$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}+kx=\varphi(t)\quad$ is

$x(t)=Ae^{-kt}+B(t)e^{-kt}\;.$

Comment: Hey Kamal, thanks a lot for the solution. But I don't think I will be able to use this as A and B aren't clear to me. In addition, I can have the data for dy/dt at every time step, H is constant and I am looking for a real value for x without any constant.

Comment: @venkateshpandian, what do you mean for “data of $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt$ at every time step” ? What is a “time step”? One second, one minute, … ? Moreover, you have to know the initial value of $x$, otherwise it is impossible to obtain the following ones. The value of $A$ depends on the initial value of $x$ and the expression $B(t)$ depends on the values of $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt$ but you have to explain what a “time step” is.